# Python requests module downloads html, instead of the file

Tags: python, python-requests, download

I am writing a small script to download torrents and am using Python's requests module. I have a link which if I enter manually in my browser redirects me to a page on which after waiting a second or two starts downloading the torrent.

Naturally the .get() method of requests returns this page rather than the torrent as its contents. How can I get a link so that I can feed it to the get() method to get the file itself?

Comment: It's hard to debug a code we can't see, operating on a URL we don't know.

Comment: Share the link we will be able to tell you how to download using python either by using some simple scrapers or xpath parser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing the page you are referring to, what is likely happening is that the link you are passing to `.get` is a HTML page that contains the download links for the files you seek. What you need to do is pass those download links into `.get`.

For example:

```
<!-- https://example.com/index.html -->

<html>
    <body>
        <img src="https://example.com/myCatPicture.png" />
    </body>
</html>
```

If we run `get("https://example.com")` we will get the source above, but if we run `get("https://example.com/myCatPicture.png")` we will get the cat picture we so wantingly desire.

Comment: You were absolutely right. I also figured that and I already fixed it, but thanks this really is the reason.